# Why can't I start my web server after trying to import passport?

Tags: oauth, passport.js

I'm trying to substitute my manual auth login route in my web app for Passport local authentication.
I can't start my web app as it says passport.initialize() is not a function.
If I move it down then it says the authenticate function is not a function in the api file.

Web-server file

```
    /**
     * This module is used to start the webserver and configure it to recieve requests.
     * It starts the webserver on port 3000. (http://localhost:3000)
     */
    import * as services from './seca-services.mjs';

    const secret = "dd1a410dbed8c9d868b5babc4d707e0bb04a7965da64baab7a43e499d3be7d43";


    import express from 'express';
    import secaWebApi from './seca-web-api.mjs';
    import * as path from "path";
    import * as dataMem from "./seca-data-mem.mjs";
    import * as passport from 'passport'
    import LocalStrategy from 'passport-local';
    import session from 'express-session';
    import * as authUtils from './Utils/auth-utils.mjs';


    /*import passport from 'passport'
    import BearerStrategy from 'passport-http-bearer'*/

    const __filename = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
    const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

    const application = express();

    const PORT = 3000;

    application.use(express.json());


    application.use(session({
        secret: secret,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));


    application.use(passport.initialize());
    application.use(passport.session());


    application.use('/', secaWebApi());

    application.use(express.static('public'));

    application.use((req, res) => {
        res.status(404).json({error: 'Not Found'});
    });

    application.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
    });






    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
        async(username, password, done) => {
            try {
                const user = await dataMem.getUserByName(username);
                if(!user || !await services.loginUser(username,password)){
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username or password.'});
                }
                authUtils.setUserToken(user.uuid);
                return done(null, user);
            } catch (error) {
                return done(error);
            }

        }
    ));


    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
        done(null, user.uuid);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await dataMem.getUserByUUID(id);
            done(null, user);
        } catch (error) {
            done(error);
        }
    });

    export { application };
```

API file:

```
import * as services from './seca-services.mjs';
import * as express from 'express';
import {CustomError} from "./Class Extensions/errors.mjs";
import * as passport from 'passport'
import * as authUtils from './Utils/auth-utils.mjs';


/**
 * This module is used to configure the SECA API Routes, and handle the requests and respective errors.
 * It interacts directly with the service module.
 */


//--------------------Helper functions--------------------//


/**
 * This function is used to get the token from the request's Authorization header.
 * @param req
 * @returns Bearer Token
 */
async function getToken(req) {
    const token = await req.get("Authorization")
    const split = token.split(" ")[1];
    return split
}

// This is the express router that will be exported
const expressRouter = express.Router();

/**
 * This function is used to catch the errors and send the respective responses.
 * @param error
 * @param res
 */
function errorCatching(error, res) {
    if (error instanceof CustomError) {
        res.status(error.statusCode).json({error: error.message});

    } else if (error instanceof Error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: 'Internal error'});

    }
}


//--------------------MAIN FUNCTIONS--------------------//

export default () => {
    expressRouter.post('/users/create', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const {username, password} = req.body;
            await services.createUser(username, password, res);
            res.status(200).json({message: 'User created successfully'});
        } catch (error) {
            errorCatching(error, res);
        }
    });

    expressRouter.post('/users/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
        const token = authUtils.getUserToken();
        res.status(200).json({ token: token });
    });
    expressRouter.post('/groups/create', async (req, res) => {


        try {
            const {name, description} = req.body;
            const UUID = await getToken(req);
            await services.createGroup(UUID, name, description);
            res.status(200).json({message: 'Group created successfully'});
        } catch (error) {
            errorCatching(error, res);
        }

    });


    expressRouter.post('/groups/delete', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const {id} = req.body;
            const UUID = await getToken(req);
            await services.deleteGroup(UUID, id);
            res.status(200).json({message: 'Group deleted successfully'});
        } catch (error) {
            errorCatching(error, res);
        }

    });

    expressRouter.post('/groups/edit', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const {id, newName, newDescription} = req.body;
            const UUID = await getToken(req);
            await services.editGroup(UUID, id, newName, newDescription, res);
            res.status(200).json({message: 'Group edited successfully'});
        } catch (error) {
            errorCatching(error, res);
        }
    });

    expressRouter.get('/groups/list', async (req, res) => {

        try {
            const UUID = await getToken(req);
            const groups = await services.listAllGroups(UUID);
            res.status(200).json(groups);
        } catch (error) {
            errorCatching(error, res);
        }
    });

    expressRouter.post('/groups/get/details', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const {id} = req.body;
            const UUID = await getToken(req);
            const groupDetails = await services.getGroupDetails(UUID, id);
            res.status(200).json(groupDetails);
        } catch (error) {
            errorCatching(error, res);
        }
    });

    expressRouter.post('/groups/add/event', async (req, res) => {

        try {
            const {id, eventID} = req.body;
            const UUID = await getToken(req);
            const event = await services.getEvent(eventID);
            await services.addEvent(event, UUID, id);
            res.status(200).json({message: 'Event added successfully'});
        } catch (error) {
            errorCatching(error, res);
        }
    });

    expressRouter.post('/groups/remove/event', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const {id, eventID} = req.body;
            const UUID = await getToken(req);
            const event = await services.findGroupEvent(eventID, UUID, id);
            await services.removeEventFromGroup(UUID, id, event, res);
            res.status(200).json({message: 'Event removed successfully'});
        } catch (error) {
            errorCatching(error, res);
        }
    });


    expressRouter.post('/events/popular', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const UUID = await getToken(req);
            const {size, page} = req.body;
            const events = await services.getPopularEvents(UUID, size, page, res);
            res.status(200).json(events);
        } catch (error) {
            errorCatching(error, res);
        }
    });


    expressRouter.post('/events/search', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const UUID = await getToken(req);
            const {size, page, keyword} = req.body;
            const events = await services.searchByName(UUID, keyword, size, page);
            res.status(200).json(events);
        } catch (error) {
            errorCatching(error, res);
        }
    });


    return expressRouter;

}
```

I was expecting the app to run as before but used Passport to authenticate